# How do I create a progress bar for multiple mixed commands?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

Trying to run a script that saves multiple files, registry keys, etc. to a central location on logout and then restores all the data on login with a progress bar. The backup script isn't the issue. The login script is. The one I have was created by someone else and takes too long.
This is the kind of stuff in the restore script:

```
reg import 'C:\Backup\msedge.reg' 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Edge\'
Expand-Archive -Path 'C:\Backup\edgesettings.zip' "$env:localappdata\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default"
```

It doesn't need to be a popup window. I'm just wondering if it's possible to use Write-Progress on the progress of the commands running and how that would look. Everything I try to find on it talks about using a ForEach() command which requires a variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.Foreach()` doesn't require a *variable*. The best way *I* can think of to using `Write-Progress`, is calculating everything you'll be doing ahead of time, then passing the progress to `Write-Progress` one at a time.

Comment: Think of write progress as a known list of items X long. All you do is use the Write-Progress comand to tell it how far along that list it has got.